# Чем структурное программирование отличается от процедурного?

Tags: терминология

Чем структурное программирование отличается от процедурного?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вообще эти термины друг другу не противоречат. Давайте для начала разберемся что есть что.

Структурное программирование - это методология, которая позволяет писать программу как набор блоков. Такими блоками являются ветвления, циклы, последовательность операторов, процедуры. На самом деле все имели с этим дело, когда рисовали блок-схему программы. Идея в том, что нам не нужны такие низкоуровневые вещи как инструкция перехода (goto).

А понятие процедурного программирования может или быть синонимично императивному программированию (т.е. мы задаем программу как последовательность инструкций), или подразумевать программирование с использованием подпрограмм, т.е. по сути вариант структурного программирования.

Так что получается, что нужно смотреть что конкретно подразумевалось в конкретном контексте. Сейчас же, наверное, когда говорят процедурное, то имеют в виду, что речь не об ООП.

Comment: А модульное программирование от функционального чем отличается?

Comment: Функциональное - подразумевает использование функций и только их. При этом функции не имеют побочных эффектов, что позволяет сразу реализовать много интересных вещей, например, "ленивые" вычисления.

Модульное же - просто дает возможность разбиения программы на модули, которые потом могут быть задействованы в других проектах и программах.

Comment: А вообще на википедии все разъяснено вполне доступнр :-)

Comment: Получается модульное может быть структурным?

Comment: @gecube вообще-то про функциональное программирование пишут, что там функции -- граждане первого порядка, т.е. над ними допустимы такие действия, как и над другими объектами. На практике это не совсем так, но это уже детали. А что "функции и только они" -- это уже перебор. Константы там тоже есть. И переменные тоже (правда зачастую immutable).

Answer (score 5):

Процедурное программирование означает следование императивному стилю (в отличие от функционального).  Ну, то есть, мы говорим компьютеру очень подробно: когда и что ему нужно сделать.  Не доверяем его интеллекту, считаем его, железку электрическую, глупее нас самих.  Многим программистам приятно думать, что они умнее компьютера, и вообще венец эволюции, вот поэтому и сторонников у императивного стиля больше.

Структурное программирование - это титул мифического рыцаря, который поразил злого дракона GOTO и погнал его по всем землям, чтобы нигде потомков его не осталось.  Так вот добро победило зло.  Пафоса было много, не счесть числа книжкам, про сию великую битву написанных.  А что в результате?  Прошло 30 лет, и люди снова украдкой выращивают себе этих дракончиков, отстаивая право держать их в своём любимом языке.  Нужны потому что они, змеёныши.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff а поподробнее с вот этого места можно?

      Прошло 30 лет, и люди снова украдкой выращивают себе этих дракончиков, отстаивая право держать их в своём любимом языке. Нужны потому что они, змеёныши.

Comment: @alexlz - Эта тема отдельного вопроса и отдельного обсуждения (в этой ветке это будет оффтопик).  Хотя краткий пример приведу: в Lua оператор Goto появился в версии 5.2 (т.е., всего год назад), раньше его в языке не было.  Твой вопрос наводит на мысль создать опрос для определения процентного количества гоутуфобов на хэшкоде.  Возможно ли создать опрос на этом сайте?

Comment: Соглашусь - без goto обойтись можно, но лучше когда он есть - некоторые алгоритмы становятся проще. В остальном же - лучше его не использовать.