# Отличие структурной и процедурной парадигм программирования

Tags: алгоритм, терминология

Похожий вопрос уже [задавался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/214035/272265), но хочется получить дополнительную информацию с кодом.

Можете ли представить два примера исходного кода (на любом языке), где выполняется одна и та же задача, но в 1-ом случае используется структурный подход, а во 2-ом процедурный?

Comment: Неужели никто не может представить простой пример? Или все только в теории знают что это такое. Я тоже к стати википедию читал и там написано что в структурном не используется оператор goto. И что, только в этом отличие? Или ещё пишут, что в структурном подходе программа разделяется на блоки: ветвления, циклы, последовательность операторов и подпрограммы. А что, в процедурном подходе этого нет?

Comment: это как рыбу о воде спрашивать. Ткните случайно в любой кусок кода на github и вы крайне вероятно увидите пример структурного программирования (и скорее всего одновременно и процедурного)

Comment: jfs, ну раз вам это так просто, то прошу Вас если не сложно этот код в студию.

Comment: вот [мой последний ответ (обе парадигмы иллюстрирует)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/739977/23044) (на Питоне и С++)

Comment: Благодарю за пример, но на мой взгляд всё равно не было предоставлено чёткого примера с процедурным и структурным подходом. Вы предоставили функцию которая удаляет значения из списка при определённых условиях.... Это какой подход? Процедурный? Структурный?

Comment: что вы думаете фраза "обе парадигмы" означает?

Comment: Извиняюсь, тогда какой участок кода процедурный, а какой структурный? Там я смотрю есть цикл, ветвление и линейность и нет goto. Получается структурный? Но ведь это и процедурным подходом можно назвать. Что-то как-то не одназначано.

Comment: *весь* пример *одновременно* и тем и другим является. Если вас это так интересует, прочтите оригинальную статью https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf (полторы странички)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь и статью, обязательно почитаю.