# Сравнить значения в односвязном списке, чтобы удалить подсписки, которые идут не по порядку

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста. Есть список со значениями:

> 4,5,6,3,1,2

В результате, мне нужно получить:

> 4,5,6,1,2

Нужно удалить подсписки, которые идут не по порядку.

В данном главном списке последовательность от `4` до `6` идет по порядку - мы ее оставляем.`3` идет не по порядку, поэтому ее нужно удалить.Следующая последовательность `1,2` оставляем,т.к значения идут по порядку.

Не могу понять, как мне добраться до следующего значения в списке и сравнить его с предыдущем.

Функция, которая  выдает результат :`4 3 1`

```
struct list * Ssort(struct list *root)
{
    struct list *new_root = NULL;

    while (root != NULL)
    {
        struct list *node = root;
        root = root->next;

        if (new_root == NULL || node->data < new_root->data)
        {
            node->next = new_root;
            new_root = node;
        }

    }

    return new_root;
}
```

Comment: Даже интересно - а почему именно 3 надо выбросить? Или это секрет, и мы должны разбираться с завязанными глазами? :)

Comment: @Harry         Не секрет, извините. 3 нужно выбросить, так как нужна  порядковая последовательность. Т.е. мой главный список делиться на два под списка: `4,5,6` и `1,2`. Вопрос изменю.

Comment: Но после удаления 3 получаем `6,1` - что тоже явно не по порядку?

Comment: А сравнивать... ну, если вы сейчас в `node`, то текущее значение - `node->data`, а следующее, если `node->next` не `nullptr`, соответственно, `node->next->data`. В чем проблема их сравнить?...

Comment: @Harry          Да, вы правы. Поэтому я хотел их выводить , как отдельные списки. Но не дошел до этого, так как не получается сравнить..Не могли бы вы показать, если не трудно, сравнение ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [на исполняемом псевдо-коде алгоритм (на Питоне)](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20remove_out_of_order_nodes%28head%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20last%20%3D%20None%0A%20%20%20%20while%20head%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20last%20and%20%28last.value%20%2B%201%29%20!%3D%20head.value%3A%20%20%23%20out%20of%20order%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20last.next%20%3D%20head.next%20%20%23%20remove%20node%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20last%20%3D%20None%20%23%20start%20new%20run%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%20%23%20new%20increasing%20run%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20last%20%3D%20head%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20head%20%3D%20head.next%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Aclass%20Node%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Linked%20list%3A%20value%20and%20a%20link%20to%20the%20next%20or%20None.%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self,%20value,%20next%3DNone%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.value%20%3D%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.next%20%3D%20next%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Adef%20make_list%28*args%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20reduce%28lambda%20lst,%20value%3A%20Node%28value,%20lst%29,%20reversed%28args%29,%20None%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Adef%20print_list%28head%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20while%20head%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%20head.value,%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20head%20%3D%20head.next%0A%20%20%20%20print%0A%20%20%20%20%0Ahead%20%3D%20make_list%284,%205,%206,%203,%201,%202%29%0Aprint_list%28head%29%0Aremove_out_of_order_nodes%28head%29%0Aprint_list%28head%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=74&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) (нажимая на <kbd>Forward></kbd> кнопку можно наблюдать, как список растёт, как элементы обходятся, удаляются). На С++ (не тестировано):

```
void remove_out_of_order_nodes(struct list *head) {
  struct list *last = nullptr;
  while (head) {
    if (last && (last->data + 1) != head->data) {  // out of order 
      last->next = head->next;  // remove node
      last = nullptr; // start new run
    } else {  // first item or continuation of the increasing run
      last = head;
    }
    head = head->next;
  }
}
```

Так как функцию по месту изменяет список и первый элемент всегда идёт по порядку (только второй может не по порядку идти), то возвращать список не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, то что было нужно, вопросы есть. Но пока разбираюсь сам, спасибо за помощь!